# What's the difference between putting display to sleep and switching off the display?

Tags: display, power-management

When I mess with my power options, I have the options:

> Put display to sleep when computer is inactive for:
>
> Switch off display when computer is inactive for:

What is the difference between sleeping the display and switching it off?

Comment: Where did you have "Put display to sleep when computer is inactive for:"?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the display shows something like `Standby Mode` or `No signal` after it has been put to sleep or switched off there is no difference.

Concerning the signals that video card outputs to monitor, there are ways to send a monitor a command to enter standby mode. See [How does a computer signal via VGA for the monitor to sleep](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100419/how-does-a-computer-signal-via-vga-for-the-monitor-to-sleep)

The difference would be if

- in one mode, the display enters standby mode and it gets turned off (as indicated on computer monitors by a message and/or the power LED changes)
- in the other mode, the display shows a black picture but it is still on (something like a black "screensaver"). That would be a waste of the display and of energy and it is hard to see that on a notebook, but can be easily seen on monitors that don't enter standby.